# Restrict SKSpriteNode to Phone Screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I had followed a tutorial for making a Flappy Bird Style scroller.  One thing the tutorial didn't cover was how to keep the user from flying above the screen, going over the tops of all the pipes.  In the comments, this was brought up, but nothing concrete ever shared on how to fix this.  One person said to just "restrict the bird to the self.frame".  I'm not for sure exactly how to do that.  Here is the code initializing the 'bird'.

```
- (void)initializeBird
{
    NSMutableArray *flappyBirdFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        NSString* textureName = nil;
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                textureName = @"Yellow_Bird_Wing_Up";
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                textureName = @"Yellow_Bird_Wing_Straight";
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                textureName = @"Yellow_Bird_Wing_Down";
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }

        SKTexture* texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
        [flappyBirdFrames addObject:texture];
    }
    [self setFlappyBirdFrames:flappyBirdFrames];

    self.flappyBird = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[_flappyBirdFrames objectAtIndex:1]];


    _flappyBird.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:_flappyBird.texture size:_flappyBird.texture.size];

    //Category to which this object belongs to
    _flappyBird.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = flappyBirdCategory;

    //To notify intersection with objects
    _flappyBird.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = pillerCategory | bottomBackgroundCategory;

    //To detect collision with category of objects
    _flappyBird.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

    [self addChild:self.flappyBird];

}
```

I tried to put in `_flappyBird.frame = self.frame` but it made an error assigning to a read-only property.  Any suggestions for what I can do to keep the object from flying over everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a physicsBody to the scene restricting your bird from going out of the viewport:

```
//In the scene:
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame]
```

You'll need to add the appropriate category/contact bitmasks, but it seems like you can handle that.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried `self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bottomBackgroundCategory;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = flappyBirdCategory;
        self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
`  This keeps it on the screen, but performance seems slightly down when doing this.

Comment: Can you actually measure a decrease in FPS? It shouldn't have too much of an impact.